# Проблемы с асинхронной загрузкой уровня Unity

Tags: unity3d

Решил сделать окно перехода между уровнями. Нашел в инете кучу примеров, почитал документацию, но столкнулся с непонятной проблемой.
При отображении прогресса загрузки в текстовом элементе сначала показывается "0%", потом сцена зависает на некоторое время, после чего выдает "100%" и сразу переходит на новый уровень.
Как я понимаю, загрузка выполняется, но почему она зависает вместо того, чтобы отображать в тексте проценты?
Вписывал в код Debug.Log(), через которой выводил число загрузки, но там та же картина. К примеру, "0" "0" потом 5 секунд ожидания и сразу "100" "100" "100".
На видео из примеров все работает как надо, код один и тот же. Просто скопировал в новый проект ничего не изменяя.
Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoading : MonoBehaviour
{
 [Header("Загружаемая сцена")]
 public int sceneID;
 [Header("Остальные объекты")]
 public Image LoadingImg;
 public Text progressText;

 void Start ()
 {
  StartCoroutine (AsyncLoad());
 }

 IEnumerator AsyncLoad()
 {
  AsyncOperation operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync (sceneID);
  while (!operation.isDone)
  {
   float progress = operation.progress / 0.9f;
   LoadingImg.fillAmount = progress;
   progressText.text = string.Format("{0:0}%", progress * 100);
   yield return null;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: скорее всего флаг `isDone` изменяется в конце загрузки: либо загрузило(true), либо нет(false)

Comment: ты можешь делать это без проверки в `Update()` . просто записывать в `progressText.text` прогресс загрузки

Comment: @Methorn, `isDone` работает верно. Вот, что я еще обнаружил:
При загрузке сцены unity сразу же загружает и следующую. Т.е. после нажатия "Play" вместо того, чтобы загрузить первую сцену и начать асинхронно загружать вторую, загружаются сразу две. Не подскажете как это можно исправить или с чем это связано?

Comment: Как оно может загружать другую сцену, если вы вручную выставляете id?

Comment: @Methorn, ну так да, я ставлю id другой сцены и вместо того, чтобы запустить первую сцену, потом в ней запустить асинхронную загрузки id-сцены и параллельно работать и ждать когда же она загрузится, Unity просто зависает на старте, а при отвисании резко показывает первую сцену и сразу переходит на загрузившуюся id-сцену. 
Либо я что-то делаю не так (хоть я просто копирую код из примера, ничего при этом не меняя), либо какой-то баг в версии. Попробую на другой

Answer (score 0):

Откатился на версию 2019.3.15f, но думаю, что и на других пойдет.
Изменил код на следующий

```
public int sceneID;
public Text m_Text;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadScene());
}
IEnumerator LoadScene()
{
    yield return null;

    AsyncOperation asyncOperation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneID);
    asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = false;
    while (!asyncOperation.isDone)
    {
        m_Text.text = "Loading progress: " + (asyncOperation.progress * 100) + "%";

        if (asyncOperation.progress >= 0.9f)
        {
            asyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = true;
        }

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Теперь при загрузке все работает верно. Сначала первая сцена, потом начинает подгружаться вторая. Нужно было добавить `yield return null;`в начало, чтобы первая сцена успела отобразиться/прогрузиться (как я понял)
Решение нашел здесь. Куда смотрел.. :/
[AsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-allowSceneActivation.html)